# Adjusting between Group & Single text messaging on Galaxy S4

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-4, mms

I recently got the Samsung S4 on AT&T. I used to have the Motorola Razr M on Verizon. On my Razr M I was able to switch between group text and individual text messages at the time of sending. So if my main setting on my Motorola was to send individual text messages, I was still able to receive group messages as a group and the default was to respond individually, but I had the option to respond as a group also. Does that make sense?

Example 1:  I could send a picture to 10 people but those 10 people would think they were the only people who got the text message.

Example 2:  If I receive a group text message that someone wanted 10 of us to get and we all need to be able to respond for a work project we were able to with the Motorola.  With my Samsung if I disable MMS then I am only able to see who sent me the message but not everyone who was included so I am not able to respond all.

Example 3:  If I needed to send a group text message and have it sent as a group I was able to adjust at the time of sending by clicking on group instead of individual and all the people who received the message would see who was included on the text.  Even if the main text message default setting was individual.

Answer (score 1):

In the stock messaging app: settings->multimedia message (mms) settings->Group messaging.
When this is checked, it will send a single MMS message to multiple people (all within the group), like in examples 2/3.
When it is unchecked, it will send a message to each person in the group individually, like in example 1.

All incoming group messages will come in as a group message regardless of this setting.  This setting simple controls how your messages are sent to a group.  As far as I know, however, you are not able to do this on a per message basis.